# Type Traits of trivially serializable C++ classes

Tags: c++, serialization

I have a C++ class defined as `A a;` which I would like to serialize. The simplest way to do this (when it works) is

```
write(fd, reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&a), sizeof(a));
```

and to read it back using:

```
read(fd, reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&a), sizeof(a));
```

I know that this will work if `std::is_pod<A>::value` is true types but what is the most relaxed set of type traits `A` must exibit for this to to work?

Just for completeness, this is for persistence between running instances of the application, there is no need for the file to be readable by another program or on another platform.

Comment: yip you are right. Fixed the uint8_t* typo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing the bitwise image of an object into a stream and restoring it correctly by reading from that stream is exactly the same as the object behaving correctly under `memcpy`. And for that, there's the specific property of begin *trivially copyable.* So the trait you want to use is `std::is_trivially_copyable<A>`.

---

Unrelated side note: Your code could theoretically have Undefined Behaviour. That is because C++ only allows aliasing through types `char` and `unsigned char`, and there's no guarantee that `std::uint8_t` is an alias for one of those. You'd better off using `unsigned char` explicitly:

```
write(fd, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
```

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is `is_trivially_copyable`, as per agnew's answer. However, this does not mean *trivially serializable* because of

- different data type sizes on different compilers / compile options
- different alignment on different compilers / platforls / compile options
- byte order on different platforms

Furthermore, you *will* run into problems with versioning, and the meaning of data may be different on different execution machines.

That's why I would recommend to introduce a custom trait,`is_doron_serializabe`, and have it default to `false` for types not explicitely marked as compatible.

(What you are planning *may* be OK in some circumstances.)

Comment: Quoting the Q: "Just for completeness, this is for persistence between running instances of the application, there is no need for the file to be readable by another program or on another platform." so alignment, sizes, endianness etc. are not an issue. Also, why's there my name in your proposed trait?

Comment: Still mentioned them because most serialization mechanisms *start out* with such a "it's simple because" relaxation, then grow a kind-of-version-header in, skip-this-if-you-dont-understand-this blocks, have a run-in with a changed alignment, and redundancy folding has a run-in with uninitialized pad bytes when probing for equality etc. It's an interface, better treat it like that. ---- your name is in there because I don't know anything else about your code, it's jsut an example.

Comment: d'oh! Sorry, looked for your name because I wanted to reference your answer, mixed it up.